# WebView SpeedTest result always lower than CustomTab or Chrome

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

The problem is simple. When i start a speed test (fast.com or speedtest.net for instance), the result is ALWAYS lower than if i start in Chrome app or in a Custom Tab, normally in WebView is two times lower.

My WebView configuration is simple, i just enable Javascript and then load the page.

```java
WebView webView = view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("myUrl");
```

So, the question: Why is this happening?

Comment: it also depends on if the environment is able to run the speedtest fast enough. Probably WebView is not able to. In general, don't expect WebView to show any oerformance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebViews will be a little slower than the browser as here every activity has to have a callback to the Android app layer. Having said that, see if you can disable javascript (if it's not used in your app) and more importantly check the caching behavior in the webview that has been set. WebSettings has some methods related to caching like - setAppCacheEnabled, setAppCacheMaxSize, setCacheMode etc. setDatabaseEnabled, javascript, loadImagesAutomatically are other properties that might impact the load time.